# Removing textbox on dropdown option

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="job_type" id="job_type">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="rotating">Rotating</option>
    <option value="permanent">Permanent</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<span>
    <input style="display: none; height: 20px; width: 180px; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 145px;" type="text" name="other_job_type" id="other_value1" />
</span>
```

```js
$('#job_type').change(function(){
    if (($('#job_type').val()) == 'other') {
        $('#other_value1').show();
    } else if( ($('#job_type').val()) != 'other'){
        $('#other_value1').hide();
    }
});
```

The code is supposed to display textbox when the option other is selected and remove it when any other option is selected.But for some reason when i select other a textbox is displayed.but if i want to change it and select some other option,the dropdown doesnt allows me select anyother option it stucks at other(dropdown option).

Thanks in advance for help..

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kmcxm534/**

Comment: While it could be improved both syntactically and logically, your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4hLsn2z3/

Comment: You're sure you didn't place the input on top of the select

Comment: yes sure didnt placed the input on top of select.dont no why its not working for me :(